# Referencing Fixtures between Bundles Using Hautleook/AliceBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures, nelmio-alice

Can anyone provide me an example about referencing a datafixture yml file between two separates bundles, using HautellokAliceBundle in Simfony 2,7. I need to reference author field in my articles bundle from FOSUserBundle. Im newbie please consider this. thanks. Information in AliceBundle docs lack this issue.

Ok These are my Fixtures for Group and user:

```
MB\MBBundle\Entity\Group:
Group1:
    __construct: ['Admins']
    __construct: ["ROLE_ADMIN"]
Group{2..7}:
    __construct(unique): [<randomGroup()>]
    __construct: [<randomRole()>]

MB\MBBundle\Entity\User:

User1:
    username: admin
    email: admin@local.com
    enabled: 1
    plainPassword: admin
    roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]
    groups: ['@Group1']

User{2..25}:
    username: <firstName()>
    email: <companyEmail()>
    enabled: <boolean(35)>
    plainPassword: <lexify()>
    roles: [<randomRole()>]
    groups: ['@Group*']
```

and this my DataFixtures loader Class for User and Group

```
<?php

namespace MB\MBBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;
use Nelmio\Alice\Fixtures;

class MBBundleFixtures extends DataFixtureLoader implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

    protected function getFixtures()
    {
        return array (
            __DIR__.'/User.yml',
        );
    }

    public function rolesFixturesNames ()
    {

        return ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_DIRECTORS', 'ROLE_TECHNICIANS', 'ROLE_OPERATORS', 'ROLE_ASISTANTS', 'ROLE_AUDITORS', 'ROLE_EXTERNALS'];
    }

    public function randomRole()
    {
        $names = ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_PROFILE_ONE', 'ROLE_PROFILE_TWO'];

        return $names[array_rand($names)];
    }

    public function randomGroup()
    {
        $names = ['Users', 'Technicians', 'Operators', 'Asistants', 'Auditors', 'Externals'];

        return $names[array_rand($names)];
    } 

    public function getOrder()
    {
         return 1;
    }
}
```

And for entity to be referenced, data fixtures by now are like:

```
MB\LegalBundle\Entity\LegalTitles:
  legalTitles{1..3}:
    category: <categoryTitlesNames()>
    name:  <text($maxNbChars = 5)>  <numberBetween($min = 100, $max = 999)>
    validFrom: <dateTimeBetween('-3 years', 'now')>
    validUntil: <dateTimeBetween($validFrom, '30 years')>
    validFor:  <numberBetween($min = 10, $max = 30)>
    geopointType: <geopointTypesNames()>
    latitude: <latitude($min = -5, $max = 15)>
    longitude: <longitude($min = 67, $max = 80)>
    elevation: <numberBetween($min = 50, $max = 4800)>
    dateCreated: null
    dateModified: null
    author:
```

The Loader Class looks like:

```
<?php 
namespace MB\LegalBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;
use Nelmio\Alice\Fixtures;

class LegalBundleFixtures extends DataFixtureLoader implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    protected function getFixtures()
    {
        return array (
            __DIR__.'/LegalTitlesFixtures.yml',
        );
    }

    public function categoryTitlesNames ()
    {
        $categoryMiningTitles = array (
            'CCON', 
            'LEXP',
            'RPP',
            'CVA',
        );
        return $categoryTitles [array_rand($categoryTitles)];
    }
    public function geopointTypesNames ()
    {
        $geopointTypes = array (
            'UnderGround Access', 
            'Surface Access', 
        );
        return $geopointTypes [array_rand($geopointTypes)];
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

As you see what I want is reference an Author from User Entity in MBBundle to legal Entity in LegalBundle. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your fixtures in specific order. First - keep your `users` and `articles` fixtures in separate classes/files. Then in your DataFixtures classes (where you load `yml` files) you will need to implement the `OrderedFixtureInterface` class (`Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface`) - just one method - `getOrder`.

```
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class LoadUserData extends DataFixtureLoader implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function getFixtures()
    {
        return  array(
            __DIR__ . '/users.yml',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the order of this fixture
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

This same for articles:

```
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class LoadArticlesData extends DataFixtureLoader implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function getFixtures()
    {
        return  array(
            __DIR__ . '/articles.yml',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the order of this fixture
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

In `yml` fixtures reference to user in this way:

```
article1:
    title: "Article titles"
    owner: @user1
```

More documentation on that topic: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures

Comment: Thank you so much pawel for your answer.  I have actually these setting in my DataFixtures Classes and it works if entities are in the same Bundle.  I tried using the same getOrder number like you said but then it load first from ArticlesBundle. My isuue is If the entities are in diferentes bundles when I run fixtures:load comand console send me the following Notice; Undefined index alias. This is my isuue how to load references from diferents bundles. Thank you again